# How to search in a column (containing the start of the word) the ole word?

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a select query that return the outcome like this :
A table that contains `MatrixCode` column with such values like this: `'shampo250'`, `'condishioner500'`, and `'AMO200'`.

The query will check for each word in the column whether it is contained within text

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [t_MO_MatrixCodeMapping]
WHERE 'AMO200IL351972598764' LIKE MatrixCode
```

I tried to use contain too but it did dot worked.

I can not cut the text from `'AMO200IL351972598764'` to `'AMO200'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you not after this?

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [t_MO_MatrixCodeMapping]
WHERE 'AMO200IL351972598764' LIKE MatrixCode + '%';
```

`LIKE` might as well be equivilent to `=` in your query, as it contains no wild cards. `WHERE 'AMO200IL351972598764' LIKE 'AMO200'` won't resolve the true, as it is semantically equivalent to `'WHERE 'AMO200IL351972598764' = 'AMO200'`.